# Spring @RequestMapping header with equals

Tags: java, spring, header, request-mapping

I want to use Springs @RequestMapping with the header attribute to detect an `Accept` header with the value `application/json;version=1.*`. The plan is to have another method mapped similarly for version 2 which will have the value `application/json;version=2.*`.

Spring seems to be ignoring the version value. I'm guessing it's treating the equals sign as another header attribute.

Is there a way around this?

Side notes:

1. I can't update the Spring version to support the `consumes` attribute
2. I can't change the format the request header will come in

Comment: How are you retrieving the header values? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the spring requestmapping ignores media type parameters.
You can work around this by manually routing the request to your preferred endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
String request(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers){
    for(MediaType mediaType : headers.getAccept()){
        if(mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)){
            if(mediaType.getParameter("version").startsWith("1.")){
                return v1();
            }else if(mediaType.getParameter("version").startsWith("2.")){
                return v2();
            }
        }
    }
    return "error";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's unfortunate though. I was hoping to avoid this kind of solution.