# spring MVC controller versioning

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring boot application , which have a spring MVC controller. I am trying to version my rest api using Accept header.

The following is how my Controller looks  like

```
RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/private/")
public class AppleController {

  private final AppleService appleService;

  public AppleController(AppleService appleService) {
    this.appleService = appleService;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "apples/{id}", produces = "application/json; v=1.0",
      headers = "Accept=application/json; v=1.0")
  public ResponseEntity getByappleId(@PathVariable("id") Long appleId) {
    System.out.println("version1");

    GetByappleIdResponse response = appleService.findByappleId(appleId);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
  }



  @GetMapping(value = "apples/{id}", produces = "application/json; v=2.0",
      headers = "Accept=application/json; v=2.0")
  public ResponseEntity getByappleId2(@PathVariable("id") Long appleId) {
    System.out.println("version2");
    GetByappleIdResponse response = appleService.findByappleId2(appleId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Irrespective of the version that I am passing in the Accept header when calling the API always "getByappleId" method is called, hence only version 1 response is returned.

Is there anything wrong in my controller ?

Comment: seems like accept-params in the Accept header is not being used by spring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425316/spring-requestmapping-header-with-equals

Comment: off topic dont use system.out use logger whenever possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34427044/258813 (and mentioned in the comments) Spring does not support routing using the headers like that.

If you want to support routing via a version header, I would recommend a custom routing condition and annotation - certainly if you are building a large API, it will result in less code and a more elegant solution.

You would define some annotation like `@ApiVersion(1)` that you can add to any method that is also a request mapping and then add the custom routing condition and it will behave correctly.

I have described using custom routing conditions and annotations (based on subdomains - but that could easily be switched to check headers instead) here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/spring-mvc-custom-routing-conditions.html

Comment: Thanks @rhinds for the response

Comment: It would have been better to include some code examples

Answer (score 4):

There are many options to implement versioning of REST API:

- suggested in the comments approach for manually routing your request;
- making version as a part of your Accept header value, f.e.:

  `(headers = "Accept=application/vnd.name.v1+json")`

  `(headers = "Accept=application/vnd.name.v2+json")`
- making version as a part of your mapping:

  `@GetMapping("apples/v1/{id})"`

  `@GetMapping("apples/v2/{id})`

So you need to decide which way to go. Some useful links:

- [Versioning a REST API](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-versioning)
- [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning/398564#398564)